# Java Generics : cant call a function with said generics even though type matches

Tags: java, android, generics

I have this code where I have defined two classes using generics.
 1. Section which can have a generic type of data.
 2. Config which uses kind of builder patterns and stores list of such sections.

On running this code it gives compilation error and I am no where to understand why. I have mentioned the type.

Error : incompatible types: java.util.List> cannot be converted to java.util.List>

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Section<String> section = new Section<>("wow");
    List<Section<String>> sections = new ArrayList<>();
    sections.add(section);
    Config<String> config = new Config<>().setSections(sections);
    }

    public static class Section<T> {
        private T data;

        public Section(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public T getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }

    public static class Config<T> {
        private List<Section<T>> sections;

        public Config() {
        }

        public Config<T> setSections(List<Section<T>> sections) {
            this.sections = sections;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at line 7, you are creating new **Config** and call **setSections** on the same line.

So the solutions are two:

**Explicit type:**

```
Config<String> config = new Config<String>().setSections(sections);
```

**Split operations:**

```
Config<String> config = new Config<>();
conf.setSections(sections);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I just realised it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sometime stupid errors make us to waste a lot of time, i'm happy that you have resolved your problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's a compiler peculiarity, you'll have to write

```
Config<String> config = new Config<String>().setSections(sections);
```